# Comparing character from one EditText to another EditText...and display index position on Textview

Tags: android

Suppose I entered in first edit text: "abgfab"

In second edit text I entered "b", so when I click on button first time it will show the first occurrence index position of b on TextView and when I click second time it will remove previous text view value and show the second occurrence index position of b.

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: in first edit text: "abgfab"  in second EditText: "b"   How can set the index position of b in textView? On every button click index position need to change according to index occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Define String str1 and check as global String type variable and lastPos as int.
so,

```
String str1 = "abgfab";
String check = "b";
int lastPos = 0;

public int checkIteration(){
    String temp = str1.substring(lastPos);
    lastPos = temp.indexOf(check);
    return lastPos;    
}
```

above what value return that value would be position of occurrence and  check return value should not be -1. If -1 then there is no any occurrence more.You need to call above method from your button click event.